# Does destroying a portal damage portals that were linked to it?

Tags: ingress

My wife avers that portals take damage if a portal they they are linked to is destroyed.  I haven't found anything about this and keep telling her that the "damage" she's seeing on these portals is actually just normal resonator decay.  Who's right?  (Other than my wife, who is always right.)

Comment: My spouse is right too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and No.

The only way in which a linked-to portal is damaged is through link mitigation. A portal gains mitigation (defense) directly related to the number of incoming and outgoing links it has, up to 10. So while the resonators on the linked-to portal do not suffer any damage themselves, they become more vulnerable to others attacking.

Comment: Depending how close the other portal is, it may also be due to splash damage from the bursters fired.